# How to set my apache project as default program to launch

Tags: java, tomcat

Greetings,

How could I make this happen, to convert localhost:8080/MyProject/ to localhost/ ?
I'm using XAMPP Tomcat 6.0 as my server.

I have tried renaming my MyProject as ROOT both on the Catalina and webapps directory,
but no use, the server crashed and never would run again.

Thanks,
Cyril H.

Comment: you want to run on port 80? so that the port is not shown in the url?

Comment: Yes. How could I process this?

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is to install Apache HTTP server and configure it running as reverse proxy with mod_proxy like

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://foo.example.com:8080/myapplication
ProxyPassReverse / http://foo.example.com:8080/myapplication
```

The configuration should transform for instance request to /myservlet to :8080/myapplication/myservlet . Please notice that putting stuff at the exact root is not always a good idea, because after that you can not use it for other needs (without more advanced configuration, probably involving mod_rewrite).

Comment: What the name of the file I should configure?

Comment: Am I going to include the code with the right parameters above on the httpd.conf?